# Not Able To Connect to XMPP Server on other server

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

### Not Able To Connect to XMPP Server Outside the Network (different netwok or WiFi)

Hi  all am developing an IOS app which has chat feature am able to connect to XMPP server(Ejabbered) which is installed locally (same wifi for Local mac and device) but when  am trying to connect to server which is installed on main live Server its not connecting because thats a different network! how i solve this issue!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is live server network reachable from you iDevise?

Comment: if connect with that server network  device is connecting  but through Xmpp its not connecting to server what could be the issue !

Comment: Have you tried connect from your device with Xmpp client from appStore? may be firewall or not working XMPP server, wrong ip/port/user/password deny your connection.

Comment: ip/port/user/password all are correct  but not connecting  normally it should work right if  am  connecting locally  its working fine if we change ip of srever not connecting! is  there any thing need to change apart ip, port  in the Code  and fire wall issue is not there its connecting to andriod side

Comment: ip:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx and server name : testing.domain port : 5222 suppose we have like this how do we connect  we should use IP or Domain ! locally am using domain and port its working

Comment: Use wireShark to capture packets. May be some low level protocol error

Comment: what error code returns tcp or XMPP connection?

Comment: XMPP Connection Error Error Domain=XMPPConnection Code=1 "Unable to connect to server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to connect to server.}

Comment: @Yuri     wireShark ??? am new to this how it is helpfull to us and thats  the error am getting while trying to connect

Comment: create wifi network and connect you mac by Ethernet. Connect iDevice to your wifi. Use Wireshark program (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) www.wireshark.org to capture packets from wifi to ethernet. You will see why client iPhone does not connect to your server. Look inside transmitted data.

Comment: yes when  i  made little changes while connecting to server its connected and working fine and thanks @yuri